# How to remove a value but keep the corresponding key in a dictionary?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
D1 = {'A1' : [2, 3], 'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
```

and I wanted to remove the all `3`s from `D1` so that I would get:

```
D1 = {'A1' : [2], 'B1': [], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works, assuming 3 is always appears in the value, not in the key

```
>>> for v in D1.values():
...     if 3 in v:
...         v.remove(3)
...
>>> D1
{'A1': [2], 'C1': [4, 5], 'B1': [3]}
```

EDIT: just realized can be multiple occurence, try this one

```
>>> D1 = {'A1' : [2, 3], 'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
>>> for k, v in D1.items():
...     D1[k] = filter(lambda x: x!=3, v)
...
>>> D1
{'A1': [2], 'C1': [4, 5], 'B1': []}
```

Comment: There's a 3 in B1 still...  Also, it's never wise to remove something in what you're iterating through

Comment: changed using filter :)

Comment: @Haidro: That only applies when the list having an element removed from is the one you're iterating. That's not what's going on here.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one-liner:

```
threeless = {k: [e for e in v if e != 3] for k, v in D1.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers I've read seem to me to create a new object : new dic in Eric's answer, new lists in other answers.

I think it's better to perform in place modification of each list, particularly if the number of items in the dictionary and/or the number of elements of the lists are big:

```
D1 = {'A1' : [2, 3], 'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [4, 5]}

for li in D1.itervalues():
    while 3 in li:
        li.remove(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the keys of the `D1` take the lists and remove `3`s from them.

```
D1 = {'A1' : [2, 3], 'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
def rem_d(D1,n):
    for d in D1:
        D1[d] = [i for i in D1[d] if i != n]

rem_d(D1,3)
D1
{'A1' : [2], 'B1': [], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
```

Comment: Why not pass the dictionary as another parameter?

Comment: Oh well, I thought, he want to use this only for `D1`. Passing the dictionary would copy a whole new dictionary requiring an extra space.

Comment: Why would passing the dictionary to the function create a copy of the dictionary? It's just a reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
for l in D1.itervalues():
    l[:] = [item for item in l if item != 3]
```

Note that this is a weird and inefficient way to structure your data, and this removal will take a while.

Comment: It's a horrible idea to have a variable called `list` or any other python type for that matter

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Gah, whoops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that loops through the keys and calls filter on the lists:

```
>>> D1 = {'A1' : [2, 3], 'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
>>> for k in D1:
...    D1[k] = filter(lambda v: v != 3, D1[k])
... 
>>> D1
{'A1': [2], 'C1': [4, 5], 'B1': []}
```

Comment: although it's practically identical to @marcadian's second solution

Comment: He added it after me.

Comment: @jterrace: Don't think so - his post was 12 minutes before yours. Even counting the grace period, the first revision of you answer is at least 7 minutes older than the last revision of his

Comment: I probably had the older version loaded then. His answer definitely wasn't there when I added mine.