# Delete numbers from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, performance

In a dictionary of sorted lists such as `d=={1:[1,6,16],2:[1],7:[6]}` , how would you delete all the numbers in lists (and hence also the key value pair where the list ends up empty) less than a given value `k`  efficiently? In my case, `d` will be large.

For example, if `k = 15` then we should end up with `d == {1:[16]}`.

I initialized the dictionary in the first place using `d = defaultdict(list)`.

I tried to use `bisect` to speed it up but I must have made a mistake.

> Is it possible to use the fact the lists are sorted to make it fast?

Comment: Are the **lists** large? Or is it only the dictionary that has many entries?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Both are large.  Some of the lists will be small but some are hundreds of thousands long.

Comment: What are the elements of the lists. Only integers ? Only positive integers ?

Comment: @eyquem: *sorted* values; that's enough for `bisect`.

Comment: Martjin Please, let me wanting not to use bisect.

Comment: @eyquem Only integers.

Comment: @Martjin I thought that you probably focused on ``bisect`` because it could be faster. I tested, and solution with ``bisect`` is indeed the fastest, see my second edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> d = {1:[1,6,16],2:[1],7:[6]}
>>> for lst in d.values(): lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x >= 16]
... 
>>> d
{1: [16], 2: [], 7: []}
>>> for k in list(d):
...     if not d[k]:
...         del d[k]
... 
>>> d
{1: [16]}
```

---

```
>>> d = {1:[1,6,16],2:[1],7:[6]}
>>> tmp = [(k, [x for x in lst if x >= 16]) for k, lst in d.items()]
>>> d = {k: v for k, v in tmp if v}
>>> d
{1: [16]}
```

---

Using [bisect.bisect_left](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect#bisect.bisect_left)

```
>>> d = {1:[1,6,16],2:[1],7:[6]}
>>> for k in list(d):
...     d[k] = d[k][bisect.bisect_left(d[k], 16):]
...     if not d[k]:
...         del d[k]
... 
>>> d
{1: [16]}
```

Comment: Both solutions use **two** loops, which is overkill.

Comment: Your last loop is the *only* proper solution, really.

Comment: Thank you. Why d[k][:] = v and not d[k] = v? Also, I am wondering if creating a new list and then replacing d[k] with it is more efficient than d[k] = [bisect.bisect_left(d[k], 16):], if len(d[k] == 0): del d[k].  I don't know if len is a constant time operation in python.

Comment: @phoenix: `len()` *on a `list`* is a constant time operation; lists keep track of their length.

Comment: @phoenix: but you don't need to do `len(d[k]) == 0`. Just do `not d[k]`. Or, as falsetru does here, just `if v:`. Empty containers evaluate to false in a boolean context.

Comment: But phoenix is correct, why do a slice assignment here? You can just replace the list, no need to force *another* resize.

Comment: @phoenix, `d[k][:] = v` come from my first code. `d[k] = v` is enough.

Comment: @phoenix @Martjin I find none of these 3 solutions fully satisfactory. The second and third ones produce new objects as values of the dictionary. The first one doesn't replace a value with another list object, but the instruction ``lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x >= 16]`` updates the list ``lst`` with a list object ``[x for x in lst if x >= 16]`` that, though assigned to no name, is a transitory new object.

Comment: On the contrary , in my answer, the modifications are all done in place. OP said that both number of entries in the dictionary and number of the lists being values of the dictionary are large. In such a condition, having to create new objects will weigh on efficiency.- I don't understand that an answer with such flaws gains points and acceptance, and that an experimented coder like Martjin let this remark unsaid.

Comment: By the way, I've just remarked that the question is tagged "performance" too. That goes in my sense

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import bisect_left
d = {1:[1,6,16],2:[1],7:[6]}
d1 = defaultdict(list)
k = 15
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    temp = value[bisect_left(value, 16):]
    if temp:
        d1[key] = temp

print d1.items()
```

Prints:

```
[(1, [16])]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Argh, I knew there was a better way! Updated

Comment: Next, use `bisect` instead of a full loop to cut `value` down to size; the potentially *large* lists are sorted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've never used the `bisect` module before. But is it just what falsetru did?

Comment: It is that easy, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just with a bit of testing, what if the key was `[1, 2, 16, 32, 4]`? That would include `4`

Comment: That is why the OP stated the lists are *sorted*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, did not see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same feeling as in this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17777407/551449): all the answers I've read seem to me to create a new object.
I prefer to do in place modification of list.

In the following code, I remove undesired section of each list in place (since the lists are sorted, it's easy), and I respect [EADP](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) coding style (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission)

```
d={1:[1,6,16,32,50],2:[1,5,15],7:[6,7,9],13:[10,12,23,55]}

k = 15
for ki,li in d.items():
    try:
        x = next(x for x in li if x>=k)
    except:
        del d[ki]
    else:
        i = li.index(x)
        li[0:i] = []

print d
# {1: [16, 32, 50], 2: [15], 13: [23, 55]}
```

.

#### Edit 1

I changed the code. It's not so good because I am obliged to iterate in `d.items()` instead of `d.iteritems()`: in this last case the dictionary can't be modified during iteration.

.

#### Edit 2

I tried with `bisect_left()` and it's indeed the fastest solution. It's the third code here under. The second one is corrected RussW's one. The first one is my former code

```
k = 15

te = clock()
for jj in xrange(10000):
    d={1:[1,6,16,32,50],2:[1,5,15],7:[6,7,9],13:[10,12,23,55]}
    for ki,li in d.items():
        try:
            x = next(x for x in li if x>=k)
        except:
            del d[ki]
        else:
            i = li.index(x)
            li[0:i] = []
print clock() - te
print d
            
print '------------------------------------------'

d={1:[1,6,16,32,50],2:[1,5,15],7:[6,7,9],13:[10,12,23,55]}
te = clock()
for jj in xrange(10000):
    dct={1:[1,6,16,32,50],2:[1,5,15],7:[6,7,9],13:[10,12,23,55]}
    for key, lst in dct.items():
        gn = None
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            if x >= k:
                gn = i
                break
        if gn is None:
            del dct[key]
        else:
            dct[key] = lst[gn:]
print clock() - te
print dct
print '------------------------------------------'

te = clock()
for jj in xrange(10000):
    d={1:[1,6,16,32,50],2:[1,5,15],7:[6,7,9],13:[10,12,23,55]}
    for ki,li in d.items():

    i = bisect_left(li,15)
    if i==len(li):
        del d[ki]
    else:
        li[0:i] = []
print clock() - te
print d
```

result

```
0.22918869577
{1: [16, 32, 50], 2: [15], 13: [23, 55]}
------------------------------------------
0.163871665254
{1: [16, 32, 50], 2: [15], 13: [23, 55]}
------------------------------------------
0.100142057161
{1: [16, 32, 50], 2: [15], 13: [23, 55]}
```

Comment: Thank you. The output doesn't seem right. It should be {1:[16,32,50],2:[15],13:[23,55]} .

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def sieve(dct, n):
    for key, lst in dct.iteritems():
        gn = None
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            if x >= n:
                gn = i
                            break
        if gn is None:
            del dct[key]
        else:
            dct[key] = lst[gn:]


>>> d = {1:[1, 6, 16], 2:[1], 7:[6]}
>>> sieve(d, 15)
>>> d
{1: [16]}
>>>
```

Comment: The problem is that if k = 15 you should get the same answer. k doesn't have to be in the list.

Comment: Thank you. Now it just needs bisect for the long lists :)

Comment: False code. It needs ``if x >= n:`` instead ``if x > n:`` and a ``break`` after ``gn = i``. Try your code on ``d={1:[1,6,16,32,50],2:[1,5,15],7:[6,7,9],13:[10,12,23,55]}`` it gives ``{1: [50], 13: [55]}``

Comment: Doesn't work in place. If you put two instructions ``print id(dct[key])``, one before ``dct[key] = lst[gn:]`` and one after it, you obtain different identities

Comment: Yes 'in-place' is abit misleading. Only the dictionary is altered in place but not the lists because of slicing. Removed it. Thanks for the code correction too.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> d = {1: [1,6,16], 2: [1], 7: [6]}
>>> for k in d.keys():
...     d[k] = d[k][bisect.bisect_left(d[k], 16):]
...     if not d[k]:
...             del d[k]
...
>>> d
{1: [16]}
```

Comment: Two loops again; why not combine the two loops (not dict comprehensions)?

Comment: Sure, we could write something like `{k:v[bisect_left(v, 16):] for k, v in d.items() if v[bisect_left(v, 16):]}` but it's looking a bit ugly with the two calls to bisect_left (and it's a long one-liner). I think you're right that @falsetru's `bisect` solution is the proper one.

Comment: You are now modifying the dictionary in-place; for Python 2, `d.keys()` works just fine, for Python 3, you'd need to use `list(d)` instead. Otherwise, finally correct!

Comment: Ah, haven't played enough with Python 3, but now I will know about this, so thanks.